# rotation 2 objects in opposite direction like a door

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transform-orientation

I tried to rotate 2 object in opposite direction like a door
I select orientation mode (transform orientation) to local and individual origins
and set origins to the edges of the objects but it rotate also in the same direction how I fix it[image: i want to rotate as ared line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a *Copy Rotation* constraint.

Here I've used two planes.  The plane on the left `Plane` is the one I'll rotate.  The plane on the right `Plane.001` is the one that will copy the rotation.

[image: Two planes, Plane.001 is on the left.]

I add this constraint to `Plane.001`:

[image: The constraint]

Like this, the doors will rotate in *opposite* directions, as `Plane` swings "in", `Plane.001' swings "out."  To have them both rotate in the same direction simply select the` Z` axis in the Invert row.

[image: Invert Z highlighted]